# trigger event in jQuery and listen to it in fabricjs (or js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I need some way to trigger event and listen to it in FabricJs.
The idea is that using `jQuery` selector I get elements and when someone clicks on any of those elements, `fabricjs` should change Canvas background.

```
    $('#background-selector .background-img img').on("click", (el) => {
        // so here I need to trigger event and also pass el.data to the event
        // el.data contains image name that should be used to change canvas background
    });
```

I am new to `fabricjs` and `javascript` (without `jquery`) so need some guidance on how this should work to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to fabric.js too... Because of your question, so thanks ;)

It took a while to find how to trigger an event from outside the canvas. I tried about everything using the JavaScript [new Event and .createEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#creating_custom_events)... But that just failed because the "custom event" can only apply on a DOM element and the objects inside a fabric canvas aren't.

So.. Exploring the fabric.js documentation, I found they [handle some events](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2#events) fired from an action inside the canvas, but it was not what I needed... While useful to know how to listen to an event.

I finally found the [`observable` namespace](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Observable.html). It include a `fire()` method which is exactly about triggering events.

Then, I blocked a while on how to make the changes *"appear"* in the canvas, from the canvas object event handlers. It seems that property changes on the canvas itself, using a method like [.setBackgroundImage()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setBackgroundImage), needs a callback to re-render and changes on canvas objects need the object to be re-added to the canvas.

So here is a simple demo where there is two DOM buttons:

- one to pass an image url
- another to change the rect color

```js
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
var render_callback = canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)

// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});

// "add" rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);

// ========================================
// Canvas object event handlers

rect.on('btn1_click', function(e) {
  console.log('custom event #1', e.data);
  
  // Change the fill color and re-add the object
  rect.set('fill', e.data)
  canvas.add(rect);
});

canvas.on('btn2_click', function(e) {
  console.log('custom event #2', e.data);
  
  // Set a background image,
  // the callback (2nd argument) is needed to re-render
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(e.data, render_callback)
});


// ========================================
// DOM event handlers for the buttons

$("#change_color").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).data("color"))
  
  // Fire the canvas event and pass the image url
  rect.fire("btn1_click", {data: $(this).data("color")})
})

$("#change_image").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).data("img"))
  
  // Fire the canvas event and pass the image url
  canvas.fire("btn2_click", {data: $(this).data("img")})
})
```

```css
#c{
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
button{
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width=220 height=220></canvas>
<button id="change_color" data-color="blue">Click me to change the rect color</button>
<button id="change_image" data-img="https://via.placeholder.com/220x220.png">Click me to add an image</button>
```